# Concatenate rows in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This question may be very basic, but I would like to concatenate three columns in a pandas DataFrame.
I would like to concatenate col1, col2 and col3 into col4.  I know in R this could be done with the paste function quite easily.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [2012, 2013, 2014], 'col2': 'q', 'col3': range(3)})
```

Edit: Code for clarity - I would like to generate col4 automatically:

```
x=pd.DataFrame()
x['col1'] = [2012,2013,2013]
x['col2'] = ['q', 'q', 'q']
x['col3'] = [1,2,3]
x['col4'] = ['2012q1', '2013q2', '2014q4']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['col4'] = df.col1.astype(str) + df.col2 + df.col3.astype(str)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `pd.DataFrame.sum` with `axis=1` after converting to strings.
I use `pd.DataFrame.assign` to create a copy with the new column

```
df.assign(col4=df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].astype(str).sum(1))

   col1 col2  col3    col4
0  2012    q     1  2012q1
1  2013    q     2  2013q2
2  2014    q     3  2014q3
```

Or you can add a column inplace

```
df['col4'] = df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].astype(str).sum(1)
df

   col1 col2  col3    col4
0  2012    q     1  2012q1
1  2013    q     2  2013q2
2  2014    q     3  2014q3
```

---

If `df` only has the three columns, you can reduce code to

```
df.assign(col4=df.astype(str).sum(1))
```

If `df` has more than three columns but the three you want to concat are the first three

```
df.assign(col4=df.iloc[:, :3].astype(str).sum(1))
```

Comment: sum on strings:)

Comment: This solution worked on the code that was provided but on my actual data set received a 'Wrong number of dimensions' error

Comment: That means you misrepresented your data.  Also, I have no idea what your error means.  You should post the entire error to provide more context.

Answer (score 2):

To concatenate across all columns, it may be more convenient to write `df.apply(..., axis=1)`, as in:

```
df['col4'] = df.apply(lambda x: "".join(x.astype(str)),axis=1)
df

#   col1 col2  col3    col4
#0  2012    q     1  2012q1
#1  2013    q     2  2013q2
#2  2014    q     3  2014q3
```

especially if you have a lot of columns and don't want to write them all out (as required by Kyle's answer).